# Wordpress post content disappears when I click edit post

Tags: database, wordpress, wordpress-theming, edit, database-migration

I am working on a site: greatlakesecho.org When I try to edit a post, the content just disappears from the visual editor. I am running the latest version of Word Press but this happened on the previous version as well. I am using the Project Largo theme with the site.

The site was recently migrated from to a new host and has gone an overhaul into a responsive design. This first started happening when I changed the character encoding to remove odd symbols from the posts. I was successful in that by changing it to utf16. At this point only older posts that were created before the migration would disappear when I clicked edit. I have since updated to the latest version of Word Press and it happens to every post.

I've already made sure the wp-config has the correct encoding.
It happens with all themes. 
Tried deactivating all plugins.

I also see this when enabling debuggin:

WordPress database error: [Table 'greatlak_wp776.wp_itsec_lockouts' doesn't exist]
SELECT `lockout_host` FROM `wp_itsec_lockouts` WHERE `lockout_active`=1 AND `lockout_expire_gmt` > '2014-04-22 19:52:36' AND `lockout_host`='35.9.132.246';

WordPress database error: [Table 'greatlak_wp776.wp_itsec_lockouts' doesn't exist]
SELECT `lockout_user` FROM `wp_itsec_lockouts` WHERE `lockout_active`=1 AND `lockout_expire_gmt` > '2014-04-22 19:52:36' AND `lockout_user`=93;

edit: Extra Info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the Navis Media Credit plugin manually.  I searched through the plugins folder using WinSCP and apparently when I was removing all the plugins using the WordPress admin panel, this one wasn't actually getting removed.  This plugin was conflicting with the theme I am using and I learned this by deleting all the plugins and using one of the default WP themes.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has this documented on their documentation. It can be found here, of course you will be converting to utf16 instead of utf8. http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets

Comment: I think I was able to fix this issue.  The issue now is that when I go to edit certain posts all the content just disappears.  Is this related to the character issue?  I've tried converting back utf8 and 16 but the issue persists.

Comment: It doesn't show any content? I can't find any real information if the editor supports UTF-16

Comment: Well it's weird because if I copy and paste the information in there it'll be fine.  The same happens with UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Check your wp-config file's encoding, make sure it's set to utf-16

Activate a new theme, see if that still happens. If so, it was a theme issue.

Deactivate all plugins, see if it still happens. If so, reactivate 1 by 1 and see when it happens again.

Also, check your browsers console for any errors

Comment: I've already made sure the wp-config has the correct encoding.  
It happens with all themes. 
Tried deactivating all plugins.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a Chrome Extension.  Here is what I experienced...

In Chrome - a Wordpress site loads the Add New Post screen which appears to get overwritten - this happens after typing a few characters (not immediately) in the title or body.  Updated theme, removed plugins, no change. At one stage noticed a bug in html2canvas.js but now cannot reproduce.

Tested in Firefox, works fine.

Traced to a Chrome Extension - Screen Shader - F.lux for Chrome 1.7.720 - one that removes BLUE from Chrome display (for night work).  It probably does use use html2canvas.  When it is deactivated, Chrome again behaves normally. Tried with another plugin "Blue Light Filter Guard" - not as well featured - but it does not trigger the bug.

May not be the same as your problem, but try in Firefox and check your Chrome Extensions.

Comment: The F.lux Chrome Extension can be selectively disabled per site.  I have posted a bug report for the developer.  Tried other Night filters, which do not fail in this way, but they are not as well featured.